# Meteor 0.7.1.2 installation error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am facing a problem while installing `Meteor 0.7.1.2` on my `Mac OS X 10.9`. I get the following error:

```
$ curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 100  4223    0  4223    0     0   2285      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  2285
```

Downloading Meteor distribution

```
curl: (7) Failed connect to warehouse.meteor.com:443; Operation timed out
```

Installation failed.

I have tried to install meteor on Ubuntu but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I connect to https://warehouse.meteor.com/ from my web browser?  ('https' important here). When I used a ssh tunnel proxy, it worked.

curl --socks4 host:port https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

Thank so much to David Glasser who asked me to try connecting the host via browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a transient error.

You can also install Meteor from GitHub. Instructions are at https://github.com/meteor/meteor#slow-start-for-developers

Comment: if I ran Meteor from a git checkout, I cannot pin apps to specific Meteor releases or run using different Meteor releases using --release.